# django mock sms send

Tags: python, django, testing, mocking

I have a method that sends sms to your phone, how can I mock it?

services.py

```
def send_msg(phone_number):
    url = settings.SMS_API_URL
    params = {
              ...
              }
    resp = requests.get(url, params)
    status_code = resp.json().get('status_code')
    return status_code
```

tests.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
// mock it
def test_sms_send(api_client):
    data = {
        'phone_number': 'some_valid_phone_number'
    }
    response = api_client.post(reverse('phone_verify'), data=data)

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Comment: are you running the server locally within your tests?

Comment: no, i use 'pytest' command to run tests

Answer (score 0):

I would try monkey-patching this within your unit tests.

The idea is to add a step to enable you to replace the implementation of the function before your tests are running and the server is initiated.

[Try this example from the docs](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html?highlight=before#changing-your-app-before-django-gets-set-up) (a bit modified):

```py
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def patch_send_sms_function():
    import project.app.api_utils

    def _patched_send_sms(phone_number):
        return 200

    project.app.api_utils.send_sms = _patched_send_sms


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_sms_send(api_client):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need to mock this with unittest

Comment: @Timur. this is to be added within your `pytest` unit tests file. you can replace the implementation instead of `return 200` and do whatever you wish to mock